# how to access key inside dict inside list inside dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

```
Cafe = {"people": [{"name": "Bob", "drink": "Coffee"}, 
                   {"name": "Ben", "drink": "Tea"}]}
```

I would like to print all the every `"name"`
but `print(Cafe["people"]["name"])` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try: `Cafe["people"][0]["name"]` or `Cafe["people"][1]["name"]` since it is an array.

Comment: If you want to print names with a loop, try `print([people["name"] for people in Cafe[people]])`

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(Cafe["people"][0]["name"])
```

Gets the first person.

```py
for d in Cafe["people"]:
    print(d["name"])
```

Loops over every person and prints their name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Cafe = { "people": [ {"name": "Bob", "drink": "Coffee"}, {"name": "Ben", "drink": "Tea" } ] }

names = []
for ele in Cafe['people']:
    names.append(ele['name'])
```

Or better use list comprehension (which is more readable and faster) -

```
names = [ele['name'] for ele in Cafe['people']]
```

Result:

```
print(names) # ['Bob', 'Ben']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cafe = {'people': [{'name': 'Bob', 'drink': 'Coffee'}, {'name': 'Ben', 'drink': 'Tea'}]}
```

Using `get()` instead of a key lookup - ex: `cafe['people']` - can be safer, if you have any reason to believe you may be working with data that may be missing the target key.  `get()` will return `None` if the item is missing the key, rather than throwing a `KeyError` and also gives you the option of supplying a default for any missing value.

```
names = [person.get('name') for person in cafe.get('people')]
```

Example of one way to format the output while unpacking the list comprehension for an unknown number of names.

```
print(str('{}\n'*len(names)).format(*names))
```

Output:

```
Bob
Ben
```

Example of handling missing key by supplying a default value:

```
cafe = {'people': [{'name': 'Bob', 'drink': 'Coffee'}, {'name': 'Ben', 'drink': 'Tea'}, {'drink': 'Soda'}]}
names = [person.get('name', 'Customer') for person in cafe.get('people')]
print(str('{}\n'*len(names)).format(*names))
```

Output:

```
Bob
Ben
Customer
```